# IIS 8 Wont run PHP?

Tags: php, iis, installation

I was having permission issues with IIS 8.0 on my Windows Server 2012 box, so I decided to remove & re-add the role in an attempt to fix it.

This seems to have fixed my permission problems, but now my PHP wont work!
I get this error when trying to access a `.php` file

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration.
>   If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Obviously what I need to do here is add a handler to one of the files in my php install folder (which I installed using the web app manager thing) but I don't know where I add a handler from? I know where to add MIME maps from but obviously that isn't going to solve this.

**UPDATE:** So I followed one of the answers which linked me to the PHP site, followed what it said and that seems to have fixed the PHP no running problem, but now thats opened a whole new can of worms. I'm getting the same `Access is denied`. error as before! even when i change file extensions to .html, it appears my site isnt directing to the default document, as when i go to www.mysite.co.uk, i get the error, but if i go to www.mysite.co.uk/index.php, it works fine! i have a index.php entry in my default documents, and a index.html, and neither seem to be working after the PHP install

permission on the root directory are full control to, Administrator, My user account, 'NETWORK SERVICE' and 'SYSTEM', just to note, i couldnt get the site to work at all without setting the 'connect as' option to my user account and password, so thats what its using to access the files.

Comment: What method did you use to install PHP?

Comment: i thought saying 'the web app manager thing' might of been too vague, i got it from here though http://php.iis.net/

Comment: Do you see a `.php` mapping in your site's "Handler Mappings"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this may help you;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#to-install-php

It says for iis7 and above, let me know if doesn't work and I'll dig deeper.

The process is;

1 - Configure CGI- and FastCGI settings in your php.ini such as

```
Fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
cgi.force_redirect = 0
```

2 - Then in Windows type **inetmgr** into **run** under the start menu.

3 - Select the server node in the window that opens which is in the **connections** tree.

4 - In the central pane, known as the features view, openthe **Handler Mappings** feature.

5 - In the actions pane click **Add Module Mapping..."

6 - Use these details to fill in the blanks;

```
Request path: *.php
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable: C:\[path to php install]\php-cgi.exe
Name: PHP_via_FastCGI
```

7 - Click **request restrictions** and then configure the mapping to invoke handler only if request is mapped to a file or folder.

8 - Click **okay** on all dialogues to save the config.

The link at the top provides further information on configuration examples and how to do this from the command line.  You should restart IIS once you're done.

Comment: Please describe in your answer what's in that link. Only posting a link renders this answer useless if the link is dead.

Comment: Apologies, will amend.

Comment: That seems to have worked, but now I'm getting the same `Access is denied.` error as before! even when i change file extensions to .html, it appears my site isnt directing to the default document, as when i go to www.mysite.co.uk, i get the error, but if i go to www.mysite.co.uk/index.php, it works fine! i have a index.php entry in my default documents, and a index.html, and neither seem to be working after the PHP install... does anybody have any idea whats going on and how i can fix it?

Comment: Can you check the permission on your folders?  (post results in your original question)

Comment: What's the output of [%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config http://localhost/websitename -section:defaultDocument]

Comment: That gives `ERROR ( message:Configuration error 

Filename: redirection.config

Line Number: 0

Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

. )
`

Comment: Okay, a couple of things to try.  1 - Grant access to the IIS_IUSER group for full control, then gradually remove permissions.  2 - Add index.php to your default document (found in the same place as the application handler, should be a page icon with default document underneath it)

Comment: if i run it as administrator I get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`, im clearly using the command wrong either way...

Comment: Are you pasting it without the []?  If not, then do.

Comment: got it working, heres the output: `<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
      <add value="index.php" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>` and for my other site that doesnt use PHP but uses ASP.NET but has the same problem, the output is `<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
      <add value="Default.htm" />
      <add value="Default.asp" />
      <add value="index.html" />
      <add value="default.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
`

Comment: Did you grant ISS_IUSER group yet? (as above)

Comment: the IIS_IUSER group doesnt exist apparently, so no. **EDIT** nevermind, googled it and apparently its IIS_IUSRS i presume you mean, granting access now

Comment: granting IIS_iUSRS full access solved it, thankyou very much sgtbeano!

Comment: No problem, but you will want to look into IIS 8 hardening as you're probably not very secure with all perms to IIS_IUSR group