# I can't run any PHP file on localhost (HTTP 404.3 error using IIS)

Tags: php, iis

I am attempting to set up a localhost testing server through IIS, but for the life of me I have been unable to get it working. 
I have my project folder in the localhost directory:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

The IIS splash screen works when I just try to go to "localhost", but when I run any PHP file I just get the error:

```
 "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension     configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.".
```

I was first trying with my project, but then I tried a simple echo script which still gives me the same error, so something must be wrong with how my PHP is configured. The most recent  solution I have tried is this one [IIS 8 Wont run PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908067/iis-8-wont-run-php), but this did not work.

Is there a surefire way to fix this? I have been looking at it for HOURS.

I am running Windows 8.1 64-bit. Has anyone else ran into this problem and managed to fix it?

Let me know if you need any more information, I really need to get this testing server up :/

Comment: "Configure a PHP Website on IIS", see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you setup iis correctly? because you have to care with somethings, so, give a look in the follow link [HOW TO INSTALL AND CONFIGURE IIS 8 ON WINDOWS 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2819022)

Comment: So I tried this one already. I looked closer at the pictures and noticed the first time I did it the installer didn't automatically add all of those dependencies. Just installed all the ones they show in the picture and it's working now!

Comment: Nice man! if you have any other doubt about the iis with php, don't be nervous, you can ask anything \O/