# IIS and PHP: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, windows-10, http-status-code-403, iis-10

I'm trying to setup PHP and WordPress on IIS. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908067/iis-8-wont-run-php). I also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492690/http-error-404-3-not-found-the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-beca) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura).

But still get an error when requesting my page: http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php
`HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.`

However, I am able to request the info.php (with just this code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`) and I get the expected results, first section here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}
body, td, th, h1, h2 {font-family: sans-serif;}
pre {margin: 0px; font-family: monospace;}
a:link {color: #000099; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ffffff;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.center {text-align: center;}
.center table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left;}
.center th { text-align: center !important; }
td, th { border: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 75%; vertical-align: baseline;}
h1 {font-size: 150%;}
h2 {font-size: 125%;}
.p {text-align: left;}
.e {background-color: #ccccff; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;}
.h {background-color: #9999cc; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;}
.v {background-color: #cccccc; color: #000000;}
.vr {background-color: #cccccc; text-align: right; color: #000000;}
img {float: right; border: 0px;}
hr {width: 600px; background-color: #cccccc; border: 0px; height: 1px; color: #000000;}
</style>
<title>phpinfo()</title><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE" /></head>
<body><div class="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr class="h"><td>
<a href="http://www.php.net/"><img border="0" src="/info.php?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42" alt="PHP Logo" /></a><h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.3.28</h1>
</td></tr>
</table><br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr><td class="e">System </td><td class="v">Windows NT MSFT-SURFA 6.2 build 9200 (Unknow Windows version Enterprise Edition) i586 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Build Date </td><td class="v">Dec 10 2013 22:04:40 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Compiler </td><td class="v">MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Architecture </td><td class="v">x86 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Configure Command </td><td class="v">cscript /nologo configure.js  &quot;--enable-snapshot-build&quot; &quot;--enable-debug-pack&quot; &quot;--disable-zts&quot; &quot;--disable-isapi&quot; &quot;--disable-nsapi&quot; &quot;--without-mssql&quot; &quot;--without-pdo-mssql&quot; &quot;--without-pi3web&quot; &quot;--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared&quot; &quot;--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared&quot; &quot;--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared&quot; &quot;--with-enchant=shared&quot; &quot;--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/&quot; &quot;--enable-com-dotnet=shared&quot; &quot;--with-mcrypt=static&quot; &quot;--disable-static-analyze&quot; </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Server API </td><td class="v">CGI/FastCGI </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Virtual Directory Support </td><td class="v">disabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Configuration File (php.ini) Path </td><td class="v">C:\WINDOWS </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Loaded Configuration File </td><td class="v">C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Scan this dir for additional .ini files </td><td class="v">(none) </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Additional .ini files parsed </td><td class="v">(none) </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">PHP API </td><td class="v">20090626 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">PHP Extension </td><td class="v">20090626 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Zend Extension </td><td class="v">220090626 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Zend Extension Build </td><td class="v">API220090626,NTS,VC9 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">PHP Extension Build </td><td class="v">API20090626,NTS,VC9 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Debug Build </td><td class="v">no </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Thread Safety </td><td class="v">disabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Zend Memory Manager </td><td class="v">enabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Zend Multibyte Support </td><td class="v">disabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">IPv6 Support </td><td class="v">enabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Registered PHP Streams </td><td class="v">php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, https, ftps, phar, sqlsrv   </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Registered Stream Socket Transports </td><td class="v">tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Registered Stream Filters </td><td class="v">convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.* </td></tr>
</table><br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr class="v"><td>
<a href="http://www.zend.com/"><img border="0" src="/info.php?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42" alt="Zend logo" /></a>
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:<br />Zend&nbsp;Engine&nbsp;v2.3.0,&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;(c)&nbsp;1998-2013&nbsp;Zend&nbsp;Technologies<br /></td></tr>
</table><br />
</body></html>
```

SOLUTION:
(thanks to @Kul-Tigin)

My `wordpress\web.config` file contained code:

```
    <handlers>
        <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
    </handlers>
```

After commenting that out, it works.

Comment: What location did you put `info.php` file? Sounds like there's a misconfigured setting that removes PHP's handler mapping. Check `/web.config`, `/wordpress/web.config` and `/wordpress/wp-admin/web.config` and look for `<handler>` node under the `<system.webServer>` section then keep us informed if you find out any.

Comment: That did the trick, I updated my post. Please add your comment as an answer for the bounty :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS, HTTP 404.3 Not Found error occurs in two conditions.

- The handler mapping for the requested file name extension is not
  configured.
- The appropriate MIME type is not configured for the Web
  site or for the application.

Since the problemmatic page is a script, you need to configure an appropriate handling mapper.

Before doing that it would be good practice to check `web.config` files in all your possible sub directories in case an upper level handler mapping configuration removed locally from there with a `<remove` directive under `configuration/system.webServer/handlers`.